# How to Change Colors of a Text Randomly after a (,) split using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to fix this problem but i am unable to solve it..
I am getting text from a database, a marquee text that scrolls,
the point is, i want to change the color of text randomly just 
after each comma(,) separation...
i am able to change the text on page load randomly but the whole
text is changed. I want to change text after the omma..
eg.  **Hello**, **I am**, **Nick**,
Now Hello Should be displayed in different color, and so on...

Here is my code, but it does all the text random color

```
        var colours = Array("yellow", "white", "green", "orange"), indexNo;
        $('#header').each(function (index, character) {
            indexNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length);
            //alert(idx);
            $('#header').css("color", colours[indexNo]);

        });

    }, function () {
        $('#header', this).css("color", "#ddd");
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("#header").each` is not necessary since there is only one of those.  You can just use the string `.split` method.

```
$("#header").html(function (_, html) {
    return html.split(',').reduce(function (prev, cur) {
        return prev + "<span style='color: " +
          colours[Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length)] + ";'>"
          + cur + "</span>";
    }, '');
});
```

http://jsbin.com/abikin/1/edit

EDIT: if the commas don't have to go inside of spans you can use this instead:

```
return html.split(',').map(function (elem) {
    return "<span" ... + elem + "</span>"
}).join(',');
```

http://jsbin.com/abikin/3/edit

Comment: Thanks, it wroks, but it seems like the comma is missing now.Can we fix that??

Comment: Which span should the comma go to?

Comment: Actually i meant, the commas are missing at the end when color changes.

Comment: @designerNProgrammer should the commas go inside any of the spans, or should they remain uncolored?

Comment: They should go with the color of the text and is it possible to add a whitepace before next color change?? thanks a lot for the previous solution.. its awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I just reworked Explosions a little because .reduce is for IE9 or above (I think). I am sure he can do a more elegant version than the following... but worth a shot. Though this gives you all text are random, not sure that is what you want. If not, sorry.

```
var colours = Array("yellow", "black", "green", "orange","red","purple");
var newHtml = [];
$("#header").html(function (_, html) {
   $.each(html.split(','),function (_,obj) {
     newHtml.push("<span style='color: " + colours[Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length)] + ";'>" + obj + "</span>");
    });
  return newHtml.join(',');
});
```